# How do the Virtual machine network works?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I wish to know If I am using 2 VM instance on the same setup and I wish to use heavy data flow 
between the VMs is there any possibility that I get the Timeout (let say I having one timer on the sending end which stops on getting the ack.)

I vague question is How network works in VM . I hope I am clear with the question.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account in user options.

Answer (score 1):

Networking is achieved through a virtual switch. Here's a full explanation about how VMWare does it: 
http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vmware-esx-articles/installation-deployment/vmware-understanding-virtual-switch.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, the physical memory you have on that box is the limitation of how the data flow works, since transferring is done within the memory of the host OS.